# Add text into attribute options

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, product-attribute, color-swatches

I want to add some info text to every option under the attribute Color.

For example in Color with label Red I want to add the text "Color red is a color that we are using under the products...etc"

Can anyone help me how can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Simply you want to add extra option in attribute.
[Refer this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29843350)